# how to change default email client to gmail in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, email-client

[image]

I can't figure out how to change my default emails settings in Chrome.

The tutorials online ([example 1](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/set-gmail-as-browser-default-email-client-ht#sm.000006qrxrk9u9d21tcs4i5d5lecp), [example 2](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-change-the-default-email-program-for-mailto-links/)) all focus on the double-diamond icon in the URL bar, but I don't see one.

When I try to go to setting and access the "Protocol Handlers" I don't see how add or delete services (not that I even know how to do that).

I can't imagine Google made it so hard to make gmail the default email, so I must be missing something.

**EDIT** based on comment.

I went to step three and all the way to the gmail extension that does not work. There is no way to change the protocol handlers and mine is blank.

Comment: Read the first link again and do what it says - "If you don't see this icon, skip ahead to step 3."

Comment: Also, double diamond icon in the toolbar ONLY appears when you are on mail.google.com, so if your handlers list is already empty, be sure you're on that site specifically.

Comment: I went to step three and all the way to the gmail extension that does not work.  Their is no way to change the protocol handlers and mind is blank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The handler that you have listed is for the webcalendar and is irrelevant to getting gmail set as the default mail client. Please follow these steps:

1. Navigate to https://mail.google.com and login if not already logged in. (this is the step all the guides were missing)
2. The double diamond icon should now show in the URL bar.
3. Right click the icon > Choose Allow.
4. If on windows 10, it will bring up the default apps window. Click on the icon under the `Email` heading and choose `Google Chrome`.

*Note - It appears that if you have multiple google accounts signed in, you must have the main account selected in order for the double diamond icon to appear in the URL bar.

Comment: Okay.  This is good.  I had don't that before.  BUT, i was doing it with a secondary gmail account.  You have to bee in your default gmail account (maybe it's the default Chrome account?) and you finally see the double diamonds.  Add that to your answer and I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: @dwstein updated